# jquery convertion from string to time

Tags: javascript, string, time

I have a system in development which records various times of the day in the following format:
**06:53:22** or **19:23:58** as examples.

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to convert this string into javascript construct which I can use to compare times of the day?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can parse the time with this:

```
function timeToSeconds(time) {
    time = time.split(/:/);
    return time[0] * 3600 + time[1] * 60 + time[2];
}
```

It returns a number of seconds since 00:00:00, so you can compare the results easily:

```
timeToSeconds('06:53:22') < timeToSeconds('19:23:58')
```

Comment: I see a mistake. Function returns string except int. To fix this we need to use: return time[0] * 3600 + time[1] * 60 + time[2] * 1;

Answer (score 7):

```
var startTime = "19:23:58";
var endTime = "06:53:22";

var startDate = new Date("1/1/1900 " + startTime);
var endDate = new Date("1/1/1900 " + endTime);

if (startDate > endDate)
  alert("invalid time range");
else
  alert("valid time range");
```

js is smart enough to figure it out :)

Answer (score 1):

of course you can do it, but before you should parse this string.  `date = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)` - we creaeted new object. After we can use `date.getTime()` `date.getFullYear` ..